# Relation of Corresponding principle and law of large numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, statistics, semiclassical

Is it possible that Corresponding principle can be derived from the law of large numbers? Also is the principle a postulate of Quantum Mechanics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes.
Second, no.

Quantum was more fundamental than classical. On of the famous case involved your question was about the ehrenfest theorem. In theory every classical phenomenon can be derived from quantum mechanics, so you don't need a law for that.

corresponding principle was basically people in old age saying that: they didn't know how to do it yet, but it "must be". Now we could and we did it, so people basically forgot about it.

Most of the time, you need "large number" or in these days, we say classical limit, to derive the **expectation value** in order to describe classical with quantum.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense to call it a principle right ? i mean it can be derived from quantum mechanics.

Comment: @adosar well, you do need to account for the historical reason, i.e. newton's first law can be shown as pure mathematics in conservative field, but don't you call it "law" anyway.